# Why "right click to play adobe flash player" is appearing on my website?

Tags: google-chrome, flash, reactjs, html, material-ui

I'm trying to figure out why every time I try to reload my page this message from adobe flash player is showing up on my web page and then in miliseconds it disappears, btw I don't have any flash animation on my web page.

Here is the [link](http://test.onboarding.upet.co/)! of my webside

[image: Image from my site]

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your link don't work. .:)

Comment: @TryingToImprove sorry, I fixed it, thank you!

Comment: It works fine for me. But the image flashes for a second during loading.

Comment: @DanielFJaramillo It is really hard to debug your minified code.. But in your bundled JS file you have something like this: `var e=C.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],t=C.createElement("object");t.setAttribute("type","application/x-shockwave-flash");var`

Comment: Try make a search in `node_modules` after "application/x-shockwave-flash" and see what module have that string

Comment: Thank you very much @TryingToImprove

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all you guys, the lib ClientJs has the flash component and is causing the message from flash.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to debug your minified code.. But in your bundled JS file you have something like this:

```
var e=C.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],t=C.createElement("objec‌​t");t.setAttribute("‌​type","application/x‌​-shockwave-flash");v‌​a
```

Try and make a search in node_modules after "application/x-shockwave-flash" and see what module have that string, so you can determine what module is using flash.

A fix to hide the flash might be making it invisible with CSS

```
object { visibility: hidden; opacity: 0 }
```